# Jmeter -Loop count Infinite

Tags: jmeter

[image]

Have single HTTP Request, since ramp-up time is zero, all 2000 request will ramp-up in zero second.

Question:
Since Loop count is given infinite again 2000 request will be sent or 1 request will be sent after successful response, another request will be sent for infinite  time

Flow 1:-

1. 2000 request in 0 Ramp-up time.
2. 1 request - success response - again next request - Infinite time

---

Flow 2:

1. 2000 request in 0 Ramp-up time.
2. 2000 request - success response - again 2000 request - Infinite time

In above two flow mentioned, can anyone tell which is the correct flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running 2000 requests, you're running 2000 **users**.

JMeter will start 2000 users at the same time and each user start executing your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler as fast as it can. You can see the number of requests over time using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart

---

1. If you want to execute 2000 requests one by one - change your Thread Group settings to

   [image]
2. If you want to execute 2000 requests at the same time - change your Thread Group settings to:

   [image]

   it's also a good idea to add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t Thanks for correcting me. With the setup which I have provided, I just want to understand how Jmeter will behave.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t
With Users: 2000 ,                                                                                                           ramp-up: 0                                                                                                                         loop count : Infinite                                                                                                        
how system will behave.

Comment: First stanza of my response describes "how JMeter will behave"